# print first element of tuple if any other element matches in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a tuple in a list like

```
A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second')]
```

and I am getting a variable 'B' which is possibly rest of elements in the list 'A' except first element.

For example:

```
B = ['two'] # or ['2nd'], or ['second']
```

I want to print first element of tuple 'A' if the variable 'B' matches with tuple 'A'

I have tried

```
[x for x,y,z,t in a[0] if  b[0] == y or b[0] == z or b[0] == t ]
```

I am getting below error.

> TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
li = []
for b in B:
    li += [a[0] for a in A if b in a[1:]]
```

This will work for n number of items in A and m number of items in B. Final output will be the first element of tuples in the list A which have at least one value that matches any element of B

Hope this will solve your issue

**UPDATE**

Shorthand will be

```
[a[0] for b in B for a in A if b in a[1:]]
```

Forgot to add in the first place.

Sample output

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
>>>
>>> A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second'), (3, 'three', '3rd', 'third')]
>>> B = ['three']
>>> [a[0] for b in B for a in A if b in a[1:]]
    [3]
>>> 
>>> 
>>> A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second'), (3, 'three', '3rd', 'third')]
>>> B = ['two', '3rd']
>>> [a[0] for b in B for a in A if b in a[1:]]
    [2, 3]
>>>
```

Comment: Please do not paste screenshots in your answers. Paste the actual code (and results, if needed).

Comment: That is the console output(result of the code), for better and easy understanding of the code and output of the code

Comment: Yes, but you could have just pasted the code _and_ the output into a code block as text. Then it'd work better for mobile users and be easier to reuse.

Comment: Please do not paste code as images. You can select the code in IDE and paste it. If you do not know how to format, thats ok. Somebody can do it for you but please no images.

Comment: @Ilkka that makes sense, will do that

Comment: @Rahul Did you really go through the answer? And did you find any unformatted codes? I just pasted the screen shot just for showing the working model. Nothing else.

Comment: I have no problem with the code but at stackoverflow we also need it to be better formatted. Please see your answer and answer of other which looks better? It is just a request. SO is open place.

Comment: No one care about the answer, the first one who informed this downvotted just because of the presence of image in it. And everyone starts to argue on formatting the the answer, not the solution is write or wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try this single liner and use `in` to check element exitance: -

```
A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second')]
B = ['two']
print [i[0] for i in A if B[0] in i]
#[2]
B = ['two1']
print [i[0] for i in A if B[0] in i]
#[]
```

Comment: Why you need to create a list? for printing?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there -- you just need

```
x for x,y,z,t in a
```

instead of

```
x for x,y,z,t in a[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second')]
B = ['two']
if B[0] in A[0][1:]:
  print A[0][0]
```

Comment: Perfect if list (A) has only one tuple.

Comment: @Rahul It does have one tuple "I have a tuple in a list like..."

Answer (score 0):

Do not use list comprehension if you want to print. Use simple for loop.

```
In [12]: A = [(2, 'two', '2nd', 'second')]

In [13]: B = ['two']

In [14]: for tup in A:
    ...:     if B[0] in tup:
    ...:         print(tup[0])
```

If you want final list try list comprehension. You can index tuple. No need to unpack the entire tuple.

```
In [15]: [tup[0]
    ...:     for tup in A
    ...:         if B[0] in tup]
Out[15]: [2]
```

Answer (score -1):

for x,y,z,t in a[0] is equal to for x,y,zt,t in 2,for x,y,z.t in 'tow',for x,y,z,t in '2nd'……,but the 2 is int which is not iterable.You can try other ways such as cut the first element  of a[0] than judge if a[0] is equal to b[0].
Hold I can help you!